# Scalable unordered category encoders

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, categorical-encoding

I am trying to design a neuron network for an scalable target assignment problem and use RL to train it by reward feedback. My major concern is making the neuron network somehow adaptable to different targets size (like 5-100). I have used self-attention to deal with the variable input size (the input: all resource-target pair, so if there're `m` resources and `n` targets, input shape is `(m*n,pair_len)`).

But my question is how to encode the target id? At first I think the best idea is to one hot encode it due to the unordered nature of the id data. But I soon realize that is not scalable. Because If I want to train my model on a 100 targets problem, then the `pair_len` is more than 100, and the majority is occupied by one-hot vector, which is wierd and I think may be not effective.

So my question is that is there any scalable unordered category encoders? Or I should be compromised to use ordinal encoder, resulting introducing unnessesary order.